# Create Jquery UI Slider from scratch

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, jquery-ui-slider

I am new to Javascript and trying to create Jquery UI custom range slider on my own. Below is html and CSS code for this task.

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}

.ui-slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  left: 50%;
  top: -4.5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.ui-slider:hover {
  background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <span class="ui-slider"></span>
</div>
```

Now I think some Javascript event should be attached to `span` element to make it slide back and forth. Should I use `mouseDown` or `onDrag` event listeners for this task? Please help me to write Javascript code to make this slider working actually. You can find slider that I want to build on [this link](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#default).

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, actually. You certainly can implement a slider and attach some event to it. But how should _we_ say what event _you_ want to react to?

Comment: @arkascha I am asking which event should I use for making `span` able to slide back and forth as in link I specified in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sliderSpan = document.getElementById("slider-span");
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

sliderSpan.onmousedown = function(event) {
  var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
  var sliderSpanCoords = getCoords(sliderSpan);
  var shift = event.pageX - sliderSpanCoords.left;

  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    var left =
      ((event.pageX - shift - sliderCoords.left) / sliderCoords.width) * 100;
    if (left < 0) left = 0;
    if (left > 100) left = 100;
    sliderSpan.style.left = left + "%";
  };
  document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
  };
  return false;
};

function getCoords(elem) {
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset,
    width: box.right - box.left
  };
}
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}

.ui-slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  left: 0%;
  top: -4.5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.ui-slider:hover {
  background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <span class="ui-slider" id="slider-span"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need javascript for that,

try this:

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" value="2.5" />
```

Comment: I know this. But, I want to create custom range input similar to Jquery UI offers.

Comment: @nicat9507 that is not enough similar to jQueryUI range? what is missing on this example for you?